# Red Gate source control not appearing in newer version of SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: version-control, ssms, redgate

I installed Red Gate Source Control when I had SSMS 2012. I installed SSMS 2014 and Red Gate Source Control options are not available for SSMS 2014. I repaired Source Control from Control Panel but it did not help. I have not tried uninstall and install yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Gate states that Red Get Source Control will work only in one instance of SSMS. If I open SSMS 2014 only, the Controls are available there. If I open SSMS 2012 only, it appears there too.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing won't help in this situation, as it won't properly register the hooks for Source Control in SSMS.
I would recommend a complete uninstall and reinstall. This should resolve the issue, though, if it doesn't, I would recommend opening a ticket with RedGate Support, as they are quite good!

Comment: Thanks for your input @noplacelike. I did deactivate serial key, uninstalled Red Gate , restarted computer, Installed Red Gate and reactivated the serial key. Unfortunately it did not work. It shows only in SSMS 2012.